# manual netlogon

Tags: c++, winapi

Anyone know how I would do a manual netlogon or any other way to authenticate a user on a remote domain?  I need to test authentication.

Right now we're using impersonation and calling an arbitrary function.  The problem is that arbitrary winapi function that will login.  The problem is that some domains allow that function to be called by null session thus causing false positives.

The only goal of this is to get reliable, fast authentication against a remote domain that the local computer is not added to so I wouldn't deny another approach.

This is the solution that we got from filing a MSDN ticket.

```
if(!LogonUser(username.c_str(), domain.c_str(), password.c_str(), LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS, LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50, &token))
{
    debug->DebugMessage(Error::GetErrorMessageW(GetLastError()));
    CloseHandle(token);
    RevertToSelf();
    return false;
}

if(!ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(token))
{
    debug->DebugMessage(Error::GetErrorMessageW(GetLastError()));
    CloseHandle(token);
    RevertToSelf();
    return false;
}
...

int err = NetUserModalsGet ....

if (err != ERROR_SUCCESS) logged_on = false;
RevertToSelf();
```

Comment: Please explain some terms you're using.  "Manual" net logon?  What do you mean by that?  Also, what is the false positive and what is a null session?

Comment: Null sessions are logons that don't require authentication.

Comment: I just want a netlogon to occur without calling a winapi function that requres netlogon.

Comment: False positive is the netusermodals returning even when the username and password are wrong.

Comment: The only way I can see a login occuring without calling LogonUser (or something similar) is to mimic an actual login with a keystroke recorder.  And even that won't work if the machine requires ctrl+alt+delete to get a login prompt.

Comment: This is a remote logon.  Also, LogonUser doesn't actually authenticate the user until a command that requires authorization is called.

Comment: And that's the crux of my problem.

Comment: I've used LogonUser many times and it definitely fails immediately if you supply invalid credentials, so I don't understand why you say it doesn't authenticate until some later event.

Comment: You can't use LogonUser to login to a remote computer.  If you use LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS it will always return true.  Then you can impersonate that token and run winapi commands on the remote computer.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is answer the question "are these credentials valid for a given domain which I may not be a member of?" then you might see some millage in existing things that do this. A number of Linux/UNIX applications offer NTLM authentication against an arbitrary domain without domain membership. Most use [winbindd](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/winbindd.8.html), which I suspect running on a Windows system would be asking for trouble.

Notably though there's an [apache module](https://modntlm.sourceforge.net) for this, which can run without any external dependencies. You might have some luck looking through their sources, in particular [mod_ntlm.c](https://modntlm.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/modntlm/trunk/mod_ntlm2/mod_ntlm.c) and seeing how they craft the request packets for the domain controller and parse the responses.

Comment: I think [mod-auth-sspi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mod-auth-sspi/) might be slightly more relevant than mod_ntlm

Comment: @Hasturkun - good point, it depends somewhat on which version of Windows the Domain Controller in question is running.

Comment: Yes.  I am looking for the answer to that question.  I'm hoping there's a way to do this with WINAPI but I will look into sculpting the packet manually.  I don't relish this prospect, though.

Comment: Looking into it more there are a bunch of apis for handling the authentication.  I'm looking at the example for using sspi with a Windows Sockets client which shows how to use the current security context to login to a remote service.  I understand how that works now.  Now I'm working on a way to get a credential handle from AcquireCredentialsHandle for a plain text username and password.  I'm assuming that I would have to connect to the rpc port to begin these negotiations?

Comment: Okay.  I can use manual authentication over a server client setting.  Now how can we make that do rpc authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've considered the fact that there are many infrastructure configuration concerns associated with using Windows integrated security on remote domains.  Are the trust policies appropriately in place?  Which SSPI are you using NTLM, Kerberos, PKU2U, DPA, etc?

Have these been appropriately configured for your usage scenario?

Ok... After hearing more about your scenario, have you considered leveraging a custom GINA?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380543(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: I'm trying to use NTLM.  Well I set Negotiate.  Wireshark the following:
if(!LogonUser(L"xxx", L"xxx", L"xxx", LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS, LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50, &token))
if(!ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(token))
NetUserModalsGet(L"remotepc", 3, &b);
You get an NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE packet.

Comment: GINAs are no longer supported.